# Create PWM pulses by comparing the cosine wave with AnalogRead potenciometer

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, pwm

I need generate 4 pulses, for the digital outputs, for example 8,9 and 10,11, at this moment I am using an Arduino Mega.
The pulses have these characteristics:

1) 8 and 9 are the same pulses, but I need them to be each going through a digital output. In the same way, 10 and 11 are another equal pair of pulses but different from 8 and 9. Therefore, they are altogether two pulses, only that each one will duplicate it and send it independently in a digital output.

Here is the bulk of the matter with which I need your experiences:

2) The pulses that I need to generate are with the cut of an analog input of a potentiometer that is produced with a trigonometric wave that I generate with a sweep in degrees with the help of a for cycle.
That is to say that the signals Vc and Vd (trigonometric signals) I must compare them with a control signal (Potentiometer) called Vx. That is, for each signal Vc and Vd, it would have a pair of pulses associated each in this way, in 8,9 and 10,11.
I think that this comparison of the signals with respect to the signal status of the potentiometer can be done with an IF arrangement, so I ask for your help because I have already tried it and it has not worked correctly.

3) Something important is that I only need to generate a rising edge that is with the first cut with the cosine wave, the second one that would be the lowering flank is not important, I do not know how I could limit this.

[image: Expected output]
[image: Serial print Arduino]

```
float V1,V2;
float Vc,Vd,Vcc;
float Vx;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(A0,INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    Vx = 2.0 * analogRead(A0)/1023.0;      // analog input from potentiometer, range 0 to 2.0

    for (float j = 0; j <= 360; j++) {
        V1 = 1.0 * cos(j * (PI / 180.0));  // cosine wave 

        Vd = 1.0 + V1;                     // Signals Vd and Vc
        Vc = 1.0 - V1;

        Serial.print(Vx);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(Vd);Serial.print(" "); Serial.println(Vc);      
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is simple, but the description that you used is too complicated.  i think that all you want is `to generate two pulses. each pulse starts when the rising edge of a waveform crosses a preset point. each of the pulses is output through two pins (4 pins are used in total)`  .... it is difficult to write the program when the description in your head is complicated. once you make it simple in your head, then it becomes easier to write the program.

Comment: one thing that i do not understand:   this is the kind of program that you would use to produce a pulse from an **external waveform**. ... what is the point of calculating the sine wave internally? ... just calculate **time delay** to set the outputs to their values .... you will get better PW control when you use the potentiometer value to set a delay value